# Jmeter- Beanshell code to add title in CSV

Tags: jmeter

I want to extract Response Title (HTML -> Head->Title) and want to add in CSV using beanshell. Can anyone please help in this. what code need to write in beanshell ?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to store a JMeter Variable into a file the easiest option is using [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property.

   - add the next line to *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

     ```
     sample_variables=yourVar
     ```

     where `yourVar` should be your real "Reference Name" from the Regular Expression extractor
   - restart JMeter to pick up the change
   - when you run your test next time you will see an extra column in .jtl results file holding the required variable value

   The property can be also set via [-J command-line argument](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jsample_variables=yourVar -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
2. If you still want to go for scripting be aware that recommended approach assumes [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/). You can write a variable into a file in Groovy like:

   ```
   new File('yourFile.csv') << vars.get('yourVar')
   ```

   again replace `yourVar` with your real variable name.
3. If you still looking for Beanshell, the easiest way would be using [FileUtils.writeStringToFile()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) function like

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
   import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

   FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("yourFile.csv"), vars.get("yourVar"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   ```